# Ubuntu 19.10 bluetooth does not turn on

Tags: bash, bluetooth, hp, 19.10, gnome-panel

In Ubuntu 19.10, bluetooth stopped working. I will try to enable it in the settings, but nothing happens.
[gnome settings screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVlFZ.png)

When I try to turn it on using bluetoothctl, nothing comes out of the console either.

```bsh
andrei@HP-Laptop-15:~$ bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# block
Missing device address argument
[bluetooth]# list
[bluetooth]# devices
No default controller available
[bluetooth]# version
Version 5.50
[bluetooth]#
```

```bsh
andrei@HP-Laptop-15:~$ hcitool scan 
Device is not available: No such device
andrei@HP-Laptop-15:~$ hcitool -i dev
Invalid device: No such device
andrei@HP-Laptop-15:~$
```

```bsh
andrei@HP-Laptop-15:~$ rfkill list 
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

The most interesting thing is that in Ubuntu 19.04 everything worked perfectly.

My device: HP 15-db0229ur

Comment: this bug seems to be described [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-oem/+bug/1853665), vote for this bug.

Answer (score 0):

For some weird reason, This usually happen after each Ubuntu dist upgrade, and start working by:

```
$ sudo rfkill block bluetooth
$ sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth
```

Comment: just turning on and off doesn't help me.

Comment: I'm sorry it did not work, It was what I used when upgrading Ubuntu from 16 to 17 and 17 to 18